When using Firebase Functions how do I extract Firestore Collection References into a helper?
I am making Firebase Functions that interact with Firestore. To avoid repetition and typos I want to export all my Firestore Collection References from one helper file, but doing this causes a RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded deployment error.
The simplified version of my helper looks like this:
firestore-collections.ts
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

const firestore = getFirestore();

const getColRef = (collectionName: string) => {
  const colRef = firestore.collection(collectionName);
  return colRef;
};

export const colRefs = {
  cities: getColRef("cities"),
  countries: getColRef("countries"),
  projects: getColRef("projects"),
};

Usage of the helper in a Firebase Function:
test-function.ts
import { logger } from "firebase-functions/v2";
import { onRequest } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

import { colRefs } from "./firestore-collections";

export const testFunction = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // Example use of colRefs, gets the 'cities' collection and logs a doc id
  // Commenting this out removes the deployment error
  const docRef = colRefs.cities.doc();
  logger.info(docRef.id);
  // Return success
  res.status(200).send("Success");
});

The index file that exports all Firebase Functions:
index.ts
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
initializeApp();

export * from "./test-function";

Whenever I import and use colRefs in the testFunction I get this error on deployment:

Got response code 400; body Failed to generate manifest from function source: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Note: I am using Gen 2 Firebase Functions

Please edit the question to show the complete minimal code that reproduces the error.  We should be able to copy exactly what you show and follow your instructions to see the same result.  Also you should be clear what "@/config/firebase" is, as that's not a standard Firestore module import provided by Google.

@DougStevenson updated as requested with all related files. Removed @/config/firebase for simplicity.

Figured it out.
const firestore = getFirestore() needed to go inside the getColRef function.
Like this:
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

const getColRef = (collectionName: string) => {
  const firestore = getFirestore();
  const colRef = firestore.collection(collectionName);
  return colRef;
};

export const colRefs = {
  cities: getColRef("cities"),
  countries: getColRef("countries"),
  projects: getColRef("projects"),
};

